# Display data in tabs from an API using JSON and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

Currently working on a site which needs to return data from the guardian API and display it on my own site in the tabs I have created.

What I am unsure about is how I can get the right information for each tab to display. So for example I have a 'Home' tab, a 'Politics' tab, 'Sports' tab and so on.

Here is an example of my html

```
<div class="page-header">
<h1>News Updates</h1>

</div>

<div class="container">
 <h3>Welcome</h3>

 <div class+"row">

 <div class"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEvent(event, 'Home')">Home</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEvent(event, 'Politics')">Politics</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEvent(event, 'World')">World</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEvent(event, 'Technology')">Technology</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEvent(event, 'Science')">Science</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEvent(event, 'Entertainment')">Entertainment</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEvent(event, 'Sport')">Sport</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openEvent(event, 'Most Popular')">Most Popular</button>
 </div>



 <div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
 <h3>News Home</h3>


 </div>
```

The API link is: https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=42fe68de-c20c-400e-ba2e-52bf467b10bf

After trying a few ways to get the data, I have still not got it to display on my site.

Would anyone be able to help me with how I can use AJAX to take the information from the JSON file and put it into each of my tabs. Each request to the api will be different as they are obviously different topics.

Once I am retrieving the correct data from the API how can I get it to display in the correct tabs?

EDIT: Adding the 2 ways I tried to get the data from the url

```
 <script>
 $(function(){

 $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=politics&api-key=42fe68de-c20c-400e-ba2e-52bf467b10bf", function(result){

        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            $("#resultJson").append(field.name);
        });
    });
 });
 });       
</script>
```

and

```
var homeBtn = document.getElementById("Home");

 homeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var politicsRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
politicsRequest.open('GET', 'http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=politics&api-key=42fe68de-c20c-400e-ba2e-52bf467b10bf');
politicsRequest.onload = function(){
  var politicsData = JSON.parse(politicsRequest.responseText);
console.log(politicsData.responseText);
};
ourRequest.send();
  });
```

So for the politics tab I am looking to search for articles with politics, then taking the say headline and another bit of data from the JSON to display within the tab section allocated to that topic

Comment: Edited with what I had tried so far

Comment: There was a typo in my previous code: `$.getJSON(url, function(data) {data = JSON.parse(data);});`. After you collect the data and parse it, you can access it like you can with any object or array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var response = ''; 
var url = 'https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=42fe68de-c20c-400e-ba2e-52bf467b10bf' 
$.ajax({ 
  type: "GET", 
  url: url, 
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data,status){ 
    response = data;
    console.log(data);   
  }, 
  error: function(data){ 
    alert(data); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: What about adding the data to the tabs? So once the site loads someone selects for example sport. It will need to retrieve only sport articles from the API and put them into the tab.

Comment: after the successful ajax call all JSON data will get stored in your local data variable as i have shown above in the code.

after this you can use jQuery append(http://api.jquery.com/append/) function to set your data in HTML

Use jQuery hide and show function to display paricular tab data

Comment: @Nakul you should provide an explanation with this code snippet.  Your answer is being down voted because the snippet isn't enough.

Comment: I have it loading the home page with main articles, struggling with getting it to show for other topics on the other tabs